# Firebase Auth Issue through React JS and Django Templates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, firebase-authentication

I'm using React JS to create the login page. For the I used Firebase 10.7.1 npm module to create the authentication.

Here is my quick code for Auth:

```
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
        // Get the ID token directly from the result object
        const idToken = result._tokenResponse.idToken; // Updated this line
        // Send the token to your backend
        sendTokenToBackend(idToken); // Updated this line
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error during Google Sign In: ", error);
    });
```

Authentication works fine in react JS and when i run the build and paste the files to render them through the django templates. I can see the react code rendered perfectly.

[image]

However, now when I try to sign in, halfway of the execution I get the below error doesn't matter if I allow all domains for CORS in Django:

[image]

It had the same behaviour when I was creating the same code in the native Java script for signInWithPopUp. I've tried multiple browsers:

- Chrome, Firefox, Edge

Answer (score 0):

I could not find out issue of signInWithPopUp so i used signInWithRedirect(auth, provider); and it worked.

However, as it's in Django and needs to sign as well, django will singout user easily from the server backend, but for the frontend, I created a check when the user clicks on the signIn Button it checks if a user is signed in already in the frontend, then it signs and help user sign in again.

As all RBAC controls are done from Django backend and all page render controls are from Django, i'm happy with workaround. Later will change the landing page script to detect the singout redirect and will deauth the user from frontend as well.